# Implementing Wiener's Algorithm in Haskell - No instance for (RealFrac a0) arising from a use of `wiener'

Tags: haskell, cryptography

I'm trying to implement in Haskell the **Wiener's Algorithm** from the book *Cryptography: Theory and Practice, Third Edition*. Here's what I've written so far:

```
import Data.List

wiener e n = factors
    where euclid = euclidean e n
          cs = 1 : head euclid : rest cs euclid
          ds = 0 : 1 : rest ds euclid
          ns = filter isInt $ drop 2 $ zipWith (\x y -> (x * e - 1) / y) ds cs
          qs = map (\x -> quad 1 (x - n - 1) n) ns
          factors = find (\(p, q) -> isInt p && 0 < p && p < n 
                                  && isInt q && 0 < q && q < n) qs
          rest xs ys = zipWith (+) xs (zipWith (*) (tail ys) (tail xs))

euclidean _ 0 = []
euclidean a b = a `div` b : euclidean b (a `mod` b)

quad a b c
    | d > 0     = ((-b + sqrt d) / (2 * a), (-b - sqrt d) / (2 * a))   
    | otherwise = (0.0, 0.0) 
    where d = b * b - 4 * a * c

isInt x = x == fromInteger (round x)
```

Trying `wiener 238123333 293719721` gives me:

```
No instance for (RealFrac a0) arising from a use of `wiener'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)

No instance for (Num a0) arising from the literal `238123333'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s
```

How should I proceed?  Is there any general number type such that it can be used everywhere?

Comment: It typechecks fine for me. GHCi gives me these types: `wiener :: (Floating a, Integral a, RealFrac a) => a -> a -> Maybe (a, a)`, `euclidean :: Integral a => a -> a -> [a]`, `quad :: (Floating t, Ord t) => t -> t -> t -> (t, t)` and `isInt :: RealFrac a => a -> Bool`.

Comment: This also typechecks for me..

Comment: Yes, it typechecks. My bad. However, trying `wiener 238123333 293719721` gives me:
`No instance for (RealFrac a0) arising from a use of 'wiener'` and 
`No instance for (Num a0) arising from the literal '238123333'`

Comment: `(238123333::Int)` or whatever  concrete type you want. The problem is that GHCi can't guess which concrete type you want to work with.

Comment: The type of `wiener` is `(Floating a, Integral a, RealFrac a) => a -> a -> Maybe (a, a)`; the problem is there is no type that is an instance of both `RealFrac` (which has 2 instances: Double and Float), and Integral. I would assume that the `Integral` constraint is erroneous; somewhere you have used a function only defined on `Integral`.

Comment: @user2407038: Yes, I use `div`, `mod` and `(/)`, that's the problem.

Comment: Even if this typechecks without signatures: please make it a habit to add them to your code! It prevents some errors, makes many others give far less cryptic error messages, and makes the code more readable because people will immediately know what your function is supposed to do.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I first added signatures everywhere but I couldn't play around with the error messages (it didn't even typecheck), so I posted this version without signatures.

Comment: Aha, it _didn't_ typecheck! That's generally a good thing. Without signatures, GHC may infer some completely ridiculous type for a function, which then causes far more obscure problems elsewhere. OTOH if you get compilation errors because the given signature doesn't work out, it's usually quite easy to get to the bug (though admittedly it requires some practise, since many of GHC's error messages are quite misleading).

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Thanks for your suggestions :-) Viele Grüße aus Griechenland.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tracked down the error. The return type of `euclidean` is `Integral a => [a]` while `quad` returns an instance of `RealFrac`. Since you use the value `n` and `e` as arguments to both functions, `n` and `e` must be instances of both typeclasses.

```
wiener :: (Floating b, Integral a, RealFrac b) => a -> a -> Maybe (b,b)
wiener e' n' = factors
    where euclid = map fromIntegral $ euclidean e' n'  -- convert result from `Integral` to `Num`
          e = fromIntegral e'                          -- convert Integral to Num
          n = fromIntegral n'
          cs = 1 : head euclid : rest cs euclid
          ds = 0 : 1 : rest ds euclid
          ns = filter isInt $ drop 2 $ zipWith (\x y -> (x * e - 1) / y) ds cs
          qs = map (\x -> quad 1 (x - n - 1) n) ns
          factors = find (\(p, q) -> isInt p && 0 < p && p < n 
                                  && isInt q && 0 < q && q < n) qs
          rest xs ys = zipWith (+) xs (zipWith (*) (tail ys) (tail xs))
```